# Can typing.Mapping and such be used with functools.singledispatch in 3.7 and up?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I had a function using [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) with [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) break after an upgrade to version 3.7. What used to work in 3.6:

```
>>> from functools import singledispatch                             
>>> from typing import Mapping                                   
>>> @singledispatch                                 
... def f(_):                               
...  raise NotImplementedError
... 
>>> @f.register(Mapping)
... def _(x):
...  return x
...
```

now raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/cpython/Lib/functools.py", line 831, in register
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid first argument to `register()`: typing.Mapping. Use either `@register(some_class)` or plain `@register` on an annotated function.
```

Registering an annotated version fares no better:

```
>>> @f.register
... def _(x: Mapping):
...  return x
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/user/cpython/Lib/functools.py", line 842, in register
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid annotation for 'x'. typing.Mapping is not a class.
```

Have I been misusing single dispatch and generics before, and is there a way to achieve equivalent behaviour in version 3.7 and up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `collections.abc.Mapping`. Generic classes are mostly incompatible with any sort of runtime checks.

What little compatibility exists is mostly undocumented and changing frequently. For example, `typing.Mapping` used to be a class, and the docs still *say* it's a class, but it's really just pretending to be one now. `functools.singledispatch` needs a real class.